# An error occurred when loading the first review item

Tags: bug, documentation, review-queues

I was just looking through the documentation review queue and keep randomly getting the following error screen:

> [image]

Comment: Yes, me too. It seems related to the [grep] documentation I think.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 I asked a separate question regarding the [grep] proposed change [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334406/should-i-reject-invalid-state-drafts) which shows an invalid state error. Not sure if they are related.

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem too right now