# Should I Reject Invalid State Drafts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, draft

In the documentation review queue, I just got up to the following proposed change with an invalid state error:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/71178

> [image]

I saw the following question which asks what the invalid state is:
[What does it mean for a draft to be in invalid state](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332610/what-does-it-mean-for-a-draft-to-be-in-invalid-state)

Based on the answer given there though, I am not clear what action I am supposed to take.
Should I reject this draft?
Does this indicated something new is broken and am I supposed to report it?
Should I skip this proposed change?

---

#### Update

Based on the following comment, it seems that the possible cause of this error is that this proposed change exceeds the max number of examples allowed. If this is the case, the UI is really confusing and not clear that that is the error.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/71178#commentId=17675

Regardless to what is causing this error, I am also still not clear as to what action I am supposed to take in such a case.

Comment: I also posted a question about this with the question if these drafts should be automatically rejected by the system since that is the only option that a user can take on them.

Comment: `topic created` → there’s no link. Otherwise, there’s a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: yes, please reject.

When we fix bugs and tweak settings, we also try to fix corrupted data, but sometimes we miss some.  This "invalid state" message is a final catch-all for those issues and occurs just-in-time, when rendering.

I've added some better error messages when this happens (check out [your linked change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/71178) again), as well as pre-populating the "other" rejection reason, to hopefully make the "go ahead and reject" clearer.

As we Fix All The Things!, these occurrences should no longer happen.